# Python Code for Bin, Dec, Hex string Identifier & Converter

Tags: python, base-conversion

I need Python code that takes a number input as a string and **detects** if it is binary, decimal or hexadecimal.

Also, I want to **convert** it to other two types **without** using bin(),dec(),hex(),int() commands.

Comment: Is that a sort of learning task?

Comment: consider doing checks with regular expressions? for hex its going to be {0-9,A-F}, for bin {0,1} & for dec {0,9}.

Comment: "without using bin(),dec(),hex()" So, using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) is okay?

Comment: I am trying a sample type checker with regex .. will that be okay?

Comment: This is impossible. What are you going to do with input "10"?

Comment: HAaaan !! @StefanPochmann - u made me look like a fool !! :P, perhaps there should be one more check, which will ensure only one of isBinary() isDecimal() isHexa() evaluates to true

Comment: @Kutay - I have opted out of regex approach to this one, check the new one below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if my_num[0:2] == "0x" or my_num[0] == "x":print "hex"
elif my_num[0:2] == "0b" or my_num[0] == "b" and all(x in "01" for x in my_num):print "bin"
elif my_num[0] in "0O": print "oct"
elif re.match("^[0-9]+$",my_num): print "dec"
else: print "I dont know i guess its just a string ... or maybe base64"
```

is a way ...

Comment: again the number "10" is a problem here too

Comment: no its not ... 10 is a decimal... b10 or 0b10 would be binary x10 or 0x10 would be hex; 010 or O10 would be octal

Comment: he never said it could only accept 0-9a-f ... `I need a python code that understands the type of the input whether it is binary, decimal or hexadecimal`

Comment: so I force him to use the same conventions the python interpretter forces you to use

Comment: @JoranBeasley can you help me to do the conversion too?

Answer (score 0):

This will tell you if an input string is bin, dec or hex

NOTE : As per steffano's comment, you will have to write something more to classify a number like 10 - which can be bin/dec/hex. Only one of the below functions should evaluate to true, otherwise you are wrong. Try to put this check.

```
import re

def isBinary(strNum):
    keyword = "^[0-1]*$"
    re.compile(keyword)
    if(re.match(keyword, strNum)) :
        return True
    else : 
        return False

def isDecimal(strNum):
    keyword = "^[0-9]*$"
    re.compile(keyword)
    if(re.match(keyword, strNum)) :
        return True
    else : 
        return False

def isHexa(strNum):
    keyword = "^[0-9a-fA-f]*$"
    re.compile(keyword)
    if(re.match(keyword, strNum)) :
        return True
    else : 
        return False
#Tests
print isHexa("AAD");
print isDecimal("11B")
print isBinary("0110a")
```

Output of this :

```
True
False
False
```

Comment: To clarify: I wasn't talking about your answer, I was talking about the question. Your answer is wrong and very bad for other reasons.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - can you please elaborate some of the things you think may be wrong / bad here. I would like to make an effort to correct it.

Comment: I'm sorry, there's just way too much bad stuff to list it all, but start with trying `isHexa("Ax")`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - yes you are right. I will take this answer down in 1hour, if i cannot fix this. Thanks

Comment: Fixed the isHexa("Ax") now, it works. I need to add another check for "10" - this is tricky

Comment: @Kutay - welcome, do you want the conversions too? or is this good? If you have got what u wanted mark the answer as final (its a tick mark that turns green)

Comment: @Suddev can you help me to do the conversion?